# Php while in a function code?

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying this function it is possible please help me.

My code sample:

```
# Here is my select query
$con = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'test_database');
$select = "SELECT * FROM test_posts";
$select_query = mysqli_query($con, $select);

# Here is my function query
function getPosts() {
    global $con;
    global $select;
    global $select_query;
    $post = mysqli_fetch_array($select_query);
}

# Here is my homepage get posts method

while (getPosts()) {

 # I am triying this method and tried define, and echo but not working

 echo $post['sample_content'];

}
```

I am tried `define('sample', '$post = mysqli_fetch_array($sample)');` but not worked.

Where is my mistake? How I should do this?

Comment: do you specifically need this getPosts() function? you can do an easy workaround using: while($post = mysqli_fetch_array($select_query) { .... }

Comment: yes I need, I now that method, I am triying new method :)

Comment: @IncredibleHat How I fix that?

Comment: `$post` only exists within the function. Return it, then define it as `$post = getPosts()`

Comment: You should read up a bit on scope.

Comment: Note: The object-oriented interface to `mysqli` is significantly less verbose, making code easier to read and audit, and is not easily confused with the obsolete `mysql_query` interface. Before you get too invested in the procedural style it’s worth switching over. Example: `$db = new mysqli(…)` and `$db->prepare("…")` The procedural interface is an artifact from the PHP 4 era when `mysqli` API was introduced and should not be used in new code.

Comment: : "It looks like you're writing your own ORM. Have you considered using one that's already written, tested, and widely supported like [RedBeanPHP](https://redbeanphp.com/), [Doctrine](http://www.doctrine-project.org/), [Propel](http://propelorm.org/) or
[Eloquent](https://laravel.com/docs/master/eloquent)?"

Comment: @tadman I am tried a lot of framework but problem is sometime hard find help. Like my twig and mysql problem https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51246777/how-to-retrieving-all-data-from-mysql-on-twig

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "twig". That other question, like this one, has just regular `mysqli` code. A templating system is not like an ORM. Often they're used in conjunction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by making `getPosts()` a [generator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.generators.overview.php) function.

```
function getPosts() {
    global $select_query;
    while ($post = mysqli_fetch_array($select_query)) {
        yield $post;
    }
}
```

Then you can use it in a `foreach` loop:

```
foreach (getPosts() as $post) {
    echo $post['sample_content'];
}
```

It would be better to make `$select_query` a parameter of the function rather than using a global variable.

Answer (score 2):

I run your code but I change some line  :

this is my `test_posts` table :

```
| sample_content | id |
|:--------------:|:--:|
|      test1     |  1 |
|      test2     |  2 |
```

and I add `return $post;` in `getPosts` function For sending records to `while`.

also used ‍‍`$post=getPosts()` instead of `getPosts()` to print the values inside`while`.

return:

```
test1 test2 finish
```

my code :

```
<?php

# Here is my select query
$con = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'phpmyadmin', '123456', 'test');
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
{
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

$select = "SELECT * FROM test_posts";
$select_query = mysqli_query($con, $select);

# Here is my function query
function getPosts() {
    global $con;
    global $select;
    global $select_query;
    $post = mysqli_fetch_array($select_query);
    return $post;
}

# Here is my homepage get posts method

$post=[];
while ($post=getPosts()) {

    # I am triying this method and tried define, and echo but not working

    echo $post['sample_content'];

}

echo 'finish';
```

Comment: "Try this" does not make for a good answer. You should explain *how* and *why* this solves their problem. I recommend reading, "[How do I write a good answer?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Comment: i agree with @JohnConde and could you also elaborate on the $post=[] ?

Comment: Thanks but this is giving nothing. :)

Comment: Sorry. I'm explaining it now @JohnConde

Comment: @RamazanAlkan test again please

Comment: @Alihosseinshahabi What does this line $post=[]; exactly do? Is it needed?

Comment: @Mart . No, this is optional.

Comment: @RamazanAlkan  Is your table ‍‍`sample_content` Field?

Comment: Yes I new created new table like your table but giving nothing

Comment: @Alihosseinshahabi Im serious, can you Explain Why you use this. I just Dont get it. Im not saying you are wrong I just have never seen this before so Im curious about What it does

Comment: I am triying new method.Me to curious about this.I want it and I will do it :D

Comment: @RamazanAlkan It is strange.
My code should work well.! I tested it again.
Are you sure you have copied all the code? Please check again.

Comment: Thank you :D Really this is working "$post=[];" I am deleted here :) working good thanks :D

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you're asking to make this work using this specific getPosts() function or you need this to work anyhow. If so you can do it as such:

```
# Here is my select query
$con = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'test_database');
$select = "SELECT * FROM test_posts";
$select_query = mysqli_query($con, $select);


while ($post = mysqli_fetch_array($select_query)) {


 echo $post['sample_content'];

}
```

Comment: I now this but I need function method I am triying new method

Comment: i agree with @IncredibleHat ... WHY :D

Comment: I don't now :) really I am trying this like 5 hours I want it!

Comment: "*wordpress*" ... ok, I'm out.